# count website traffic

Tags: asp.net, web, traffic

hey, i was just wondering how would I go about monitoring or measuring the number of hits my website gets. I want to do this from code as opposed to downloading a plug in to the page. It is an asp.net website. Any tutorial or code suggestions would be nice. thanks in advance.

Comment: If you try and do this in code you need a way to count each user. You can do this with a database, just increment an integer each time a visitor arrives on your page. You'll probably want to remember this visitor by using a session variable so that if they reload the page it doesn't count them again.

If you don't have a database you could use an Application variable which is server wide and increment that, however if you restart IIS this variable resets itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check out Google Analytics, they are awesome, and one line of code to add!

It's what I use for all the websites I manage!

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at installing AWStats, which works by reading your web servers logs. All you need to do it change the logging settings on your server (IIS if your using Windows Server), install AWStats, which runs as a separate website, and schedule the collation of stats with a scheduled task.

Advantages: More in depth stats, particularly with visitors IP address which Google does not collect.
Disadvantages: More effort to get up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to monitor traffic and other important metrics is to use Google Analytics. Not only can you see historical numbers for your site, but you can monitor traffic in real-time. Additionally, you can track conversions (sales) from ads or outside links.